# MySQL "OR" results in wrong "ORDER BY"

Tags: mysql

I got the following query.

```
SELECT t1.parent_id
     , t1.id
     , t2.slug     
  FROM t1    
  LEFT 
  JOIN t2 
    ON t2.node_id = t1.id              
 WHERE t1.id
   AND
     ( t1.parent_id = 501  
    OR t1.parent_id = 750  
     )
   AND t2.display = 1
   AND t2.active = 1
 ORDER 
    BY t1.name ASC
```

seems to work but the ordering is wrong (i'm probably wrong - not the ordering). its is like GROUP BY `t1`.`parent_id`...

with this table:

```
--------------
name  |  parent_id
a     |  501
b     |  750
c     |  501
d     |  750
--------------
```

i get this result:

```
a
c
b
d
```

but i would expect this:

```
a
b
c
d
```

thanks for your time and help...

UPDATE:

@Juan Carlos Oropeza thank you. i ran the code in phpMyAdmin - same result. i changed to INNER JOIN and removed the WHERE t1.id (was not hurting though)  and used t1`.`parent_id` IN (501, 750) instead:

```
mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        `t1`.`parent_id`,
        `t1`.`id`,
        `t2`.`slug`     
    FROM 
        `t1`    
    INNER JOIN
        `t2`    ON `t2`.`node_id` = `t1`.`id`               
    WHERE       
        `t1`.`parent_id` IN (501, 750)
    AND
        `t2`.`display` = 1
    AND
        `t2`.`active` = 1
    ORDER BY 
        `t1`.`lft`
    ASC
");
```

same result

Comment: Doesnt make any sense. Try `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(t1.parent_id)` Maybe you have special chars there. Try to reproduce the sample here so we take a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/037bc/1

Comment: What do you mean you get this results? copy the exact results that you are getting!

Comment: BTW, this is an INNER JOIN

Comment: If you run the code direct on mySQL get same result? Additional tip you may use `t1.parent_id IN (501, 750)` .. `WHERE t1.id` condition doesnt make any sense neither. And if you want `t2.display` has any value you dont use `LEFT JOIN` use `INNER JOIN` instead

Comment: t1.parent_id is  int(11)

Comment: There should be a newline before `ASC` in the line `BY t1.name ASC`.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem... the data was in t1.name was flawed. so the query actually worked as it should have. thanks for your help guys!